# Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.544

Tags: c#, .net

I have a WPF application targeted on Win 7. While working on the app I suddenly got the Application closing error.

When i checked the event logs i got the following error:

Machine Details:

4 GB Ram, Win 7 Professional and 64 Bit machine.

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          4/9/2013 2:28:54 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: Application Crashing Events
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      HOME
Description:
Faulting application name: Client.exe, version: 1.1.0.14, time stamp: 0x516328ad
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.544, time stamp: 0x4ee9a8e7
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0010943a
Faulting process id: 0xc14
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce34fde4195884
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyClient\Client.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: b4329b51-a0f3-11e2-86c9-082e5f2a7903
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-09T08:58:54.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>7917</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>HOME</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Client.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.14</Data>
    <Data>516328ad</Data>
    <Data>clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>4.0.30319.544</Data>
    <Data>4ee9a8e7</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>0010943a</Data>
    <Data>c14</Data>
    <Data>01ce34fde4195884</Data>
    <Data>C:\Program Files (x86)\MyClient\client.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll</Data>
    <Data>b4329b51-a0f3-11e2-86c9-082e5f2a7903</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Plus i got another related error

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        .NET Runtime
Date:          4/9/2013 2:28:52 PM
Event ID:      1023
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      HOME
Description:
Application: Client.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 743C943A (742C0000) with exit code 80131506.

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1023</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-09T08:58:52.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>7916</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>HOME</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Application: Client.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 743C943A (742C0000) with exit code 80131506.
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I had got the same error(s) with clr.dll v  4.0.30319.269, i searched the community and installed the fix given in

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103 article.

After the installtion of the fix the old clr.dll(4.0.30319.269) was replaced with new version 4.0.30319.544, but today i still got this error.

Is there any solution for the above crash, is it an issue with the framework or the exe ?

Comment: Under the Debug - > Exceptions menu try turning on user handeld CLR exceptions to see what the real error is.

Comment: Did you ever get this issue resolved?